# Can't get matplotlib event handler working with Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib, boost-python

I am developing a C++11 program with an interpreter (written in C++) that calls various class methods to do work.  I want to add the ability to create plots of data using Python 3.5 with matplotlib (backend is TkAgg).  I also want users to be able to start a Python interpreter or run python scripts from within the program in order to make detailed adjustments/enhancements to the plots in real time.

So far I’ve been successful at creating and saving the plots using Boost.Python 1.65.1 as my interface layer, and at launching a Python interpreter using Python’s code module.  However, the event loops of the matplotlib plots do not run at my C++ interpreter prompt (i.e. if I place another window over my plot, the figure turns blank and doesn’t redraw).  It is only when the user starts the Python interpreter that the event loops work and figures are redrawn.  I’d like the program to behave as if the user created the plots in a native Python interpreter after issuing the matplotlib.pyplot.ion() command.  I’ve added a plt.ion() call to the Python code used to create the plots but this doesn’t seem to have an impact on the resulting behavior.

I’ve attempted to fix this by performing  Python plotting and C++ interpreting on different threads, however it doesn’t seem to help anything.  I’d like to know if I should be handling the Python GIL differently from the way I am currently, or if there is something else I can do to get the matplotlib event loops running in the background thread.  I’ve posted a simple example that recreates the core issue I am having.  Any help is appreciated.

One other thing I've tried is to manually call matplotlib's canvas.start_event_loop().  This seems to work, but it blocks me from creating new plots until it returns/timesout which isn't ideal.

**Here is the Python code to create the plots**

```
# Import matplotlib and pyplot and turn on interactive mode
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

def PlotData(num):
    """ Create a simple plot and return the figure.
    """
    data_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,2,4,1],[4,3,2,1]]
    data = data_list[num]

    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.gca()

    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y label')

    ax.plot([1,2,3,4],data,'bo-')

    title = 'Data Set ' + str(num+1)
    f.suptitle(title)
    print(title)
    f.show()
    return f
```

**Here is the C++ Code**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

PyThreadState* mainThreadState = nullptr;
PyThreadState* pts = nullptr; /*!< Pointer for the current thread state */

/*! Initialize Python */
void init()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    mainThreadState = PyEval_SaveThread();
}

void init_thread()
{
    pts = PyThreadState_New(mainThreadState->interp);
}

/*! Calls Python to create a simple plot interactively */
void PlotData(const int& inp)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    // Acquire the GIL
    std::cout << "Python Thread GIL State (before): " << PyGILState_Check() << std::endl;
    PyEval_RestoreThread(pts);

    object background = import("sto");
    object fig = background.attr("PlotData")(inp);

    // The code below will show the plot, but the plot won't update in real time at the C++ command line
    object plt = import("matplotlib.pyplot");
    fig.attr("show")();
    plt.attr("pause")(.1);

    std::cout << "Python Thread GIL State (during): " << PyGILState_Check() << std::endl;

    // Release the GIL
    pts = PyEval_SaveThread();
    std::cout << "Python Thread GIL State (after): " << PyGILState_Check() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Create a thread pool with 1 thread for all Python code
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;

    // Start the service
    auto work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(ioService);

    // Add a single thread to the thread pool for Python operations
    threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));

    // Initialize Python
    init();
    std::cout << "Submitting init_thread" << std::endl;
    ioService.post(boost::bind(init_thread));

    // Create some plots on the background thread
    std::cout << "Submitting PlotData calls" << std::endl;
    ioService.post(boost::bind(PlotData,0));
    ioService.post(boost::bind(PlotData,1));

    // Pause to allow plots to update in realtime
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(4));

    // Receive inputs from command line (the plots should update during this time but they don't)
    std::string inp{"1"};
    std::cout << "Enter to quit\n";
    while (!inp.empty())
    {
        std::cout << ">> ";
        std::getline(std::cin,inp);
        std::cout << "GIL State: " << PyGILState_Check() << std::endl;
    }

    // Finalize Python
    std::cout << "Submitting Py_Finalize" << std::endl;
    ioService.post(boost::bind(PyEval_RestoreThread,pts));
    ioService.post(boost::bind(Py_Finalize));

    // Allow jobs to complete and shut down the thread pool
    work.reset();
    threadpool.join_all();
    ioService.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable way forward if anyone stumbles onto this post and is interested.  I abandoned the Boost.Asio approach in favor of a more straight forward approach using std::future.  In addition, I updated the code to get the input on the background thread, rather than running Python in the background.  I had to play around with the timeout period to get the responsiveness I wanted, but now the Python figure updates without coming into focus and the user can enter commands at the C++ prompt.  The code below assumes a figure is already open in Python when the C++ prompt starts.

Here's the updated C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void GetInput()
{
    std::cout << "$ ";
    std::string tline;
    std::getline(std::cin, tline);
    std::cout << "You entered: '" << tline << "'\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    Py_Initialize();

    try
    {
        std::cout << "Importing python code" << std::endl;
        object background = import("sto");

        std::cout << "Calling python code" << std::endl;
        background.attr("SimpleTest")(argc);
        object fig = background.attr("PlotData")(argc);

        std::chrono::milliseconds span(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "Iteration " << i << std::endl;
            std::future<void> fut = std::async(GetInput);
            while (fut.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
                background.attr("Pause")(.2);
        }
    } catch (error_already_set& e)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And the corresponding Python code that is imported (from sto.py):

```
# Import matplotlib and pyplot and turn on interactive mode
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.style.use('classic')


def SimpleTest(num):
    print('Python code: you entered ' + str(num))

def PlotData(num):
    """ Create a simple plot and return the figure.
    """
    if len(sys.argv) == 0:
        sys.argv.append('sto.py')

    data_list = [[1,2,3,4],[3,2,4,1],[4,3,2,1]]
    if num < len(data_list):
        data = data_list[num]
    else:
        data = data_list[1]

    f = plt.figure()
    ax = f.gca()

    ax.set_xlabel('x label')
    ax.set_ylabel('y label')

    ax.plot([1,2,3,4],data,'bo-')

    title = 'Data Set ' + str(num+1)
    f.suptitle(title)
    print(title)
    f.show()
    plt.pause(.02)
    return f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleTest(8)
    PlotData(4)

def Pause1(timeout):
    '''This function isn't great because it brings the 
       figure into focus which is not desired'''
    plt.pause(timeout)

def Pause2(timeout):
    '''This function starts the event loop but does not 
       bring the figure into focus (which is good)'''
    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.canvas.start_event_loop(timeout)

def Pause(timeout):
    # print('Waiting for ' + str(timeout) + ' seconds')
    Pause2(timeout)
    # print('Done waiting')
```